# Recommendation for time appropriate typeface (early 20th Century)

Tags: typography

I am designing a program for a play that is set in the early twentieth century (circa 1911) Austria and it focuses on the upper class. What are some historically relevant fonts and design elements that such a program can include?

Comment: "early twentieth century" is too broad. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

One might be tempted to call this "art nouveau" but if you are looking for authentic, you really need to look at Vienna 1910. This is too late to be `secessionist` and too early to be `bauhaus` but either one would work in a pinch. Vienna art was cutting edge at the time, and their design aesthetic was different than France and especially different than England and the US at the time.

See especially the title page(s) and inside cover papers:

http://books.google.com/books?id=FWJHAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=wein+kunst&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qK9sT4uaEIGtgQebopnKBg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBA

1908:
http://books.google.com/books?id=siJbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA252&dq=Kunstschau+wien&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BrFsT6a0EpTDgAfr1oTJBg&ved=0CEsQuwUwBA#v=onepage&q=Kunstschau%20wien&f=false

1909:
http://books.google.com/books?id=z-EYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA311&dq=Kunstschau+wien&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BrFsT6a0EpTDgAfr1oTJBg&ved=0CF0QuwUwCA#v=onepage&q=Kunstschau%20wien&f=false

As far as typefaces: maybe check out the people involved in the `Steglitzer Werkstatt` and `Leipzig Academy of Graphic Design and Book Arts` such as Belwe.